# Adding module-info to jpa spring boot breaks the project

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

I created a simple spring boot jpa app. Because this is part of a javafx app, i need it to be a java module, so i can package it with jlink.

I am getting the following error on startup as soon, as i add a module info to the project:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [de/mkmstock/jpa/config/PersistenceJPAConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to resolve persistence unit root URL
    at spring.beans/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1786) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:na]
    at spring.beans/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:602) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:na]
    at spring.beans/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:na]
    at spring.beans/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:na]
    at spring.beans/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$$Lambda$264/0x00000000d41edbe8.getObject(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at spring.beans/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:na]
    at spring.beans/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:na]
    at spring.beans/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:na]
    at spring.context/org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154) ~[spring-context-5.3.5.jar:na]
    at spring.context/org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908) ~[spring-context-5.3.5.jar:na]
    at spring.context/org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.5.jar:na]
    at spring.boot/org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:769) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:na]
    at spring.boot/org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:na]
    at spring.boot/org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:426) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:na]
    at spring.boot/org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:326) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:na]
    at spring.boot/org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1313) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:na]
    at spring.boot/org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1302) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:na]
    at mkmstock/de.mkmstock.MkmstockApplication.main(MkmstockApplication.java:17) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to resolve persistence unit root URL
    at spring.orm/org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.determineDefaultPersistenceUnitRootUrl(DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.java:641) ~[spring-orm-5.3.5.jar:na]
    at spring.orm/org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.preparePersistenceUnitInfos(DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.java:463) ~[spring-orm-5.3.5.jar:na]
    at spring.orm/org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.afterPropertiesSet(DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.java:444) ~[spring-orm-5.3.5.jar:na]
    at spring.orm/org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:328) ~[spring-orm-5.3.5.jar:na]
    at spring.beans/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1845) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:na]
    at spring.beans/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1782) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:na]
    ... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
    at spring.core/org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getURL(ClassPathResource.java:202) ~[spring-core-5.3.5.jar:na]
    at spring.orm/org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.determineDefaultPersistenceUnitRootUrl(DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.java:637) ~[spring-orm-5.3.5.jar:na]
    ... 22 common frames omitted
```

You can see the problematic project without the ui here:
https://github.com/Barazanthul88/mkmstock

Comment: Where is your datasource config?

Comment: You can find the config here: https://github.com/Barazanthul88/mkmstock/blob/master/src/main/java/de/mkmstock/jpa/config/PersistenceJPAConfig.java